# How to fix soapenv:Envelope issue in XSD schema while validating with SOAP request/response

Tags: xml, validation, soap, xsd

I have a SOAP request :-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:retrieveDataRequest>
         <v1:Id>58</v1:Id>
      </v1:retrieveDataRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and a SOAP response :-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <retrieveDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
         <Response>The Data retrieved from the Database</Response>
         <Id>58</Id>
         <Name>fdfdf</Name>
         <Age>44</Age>
         <Designation>sse</Designation>
      </retrieveDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now my XSD schema is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1" 
xmlns:tns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="dataRequest">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Id" type="int"></element>
            <element name="Name" type="string"></element>
            <element name="Age" type="int"></element>
            <element name="Designation" type="string"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="dataResponse">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Response" type="string"></element>
            <element name="Id" type="int"></element>
            <element name="Name" type="string"></element>
            <element name="Age" type="int"></element>
            <element name="Designation" type="string"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <element name="insertDataRequest" type="tns:dataRequest"></element>

    <element name="insertDataResponse" type="tns:dataResponse"></element>


    <element name="retrieveDataRequest" type="tns:retrieveRequest"></element>

    <element name="retrieveDataResponse" type="tns:dataResponse"></element>

    <complexType name="retrieveRequest">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Id" type="int"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <element name="updateDataRequest" type="tns:dataRequest"></element>

    <element name="updateDataRespone" type="tns:dataResponse"></element>

    <complexType name="deleteRequest">
        <sequence>
            <element name="ID" type="int"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <element name="deleteDataRequest" type="tns:deleteRequest"></element>

    <element name="deleteDataResponse" type="tns:dataResponse"></element>
</schema>
```

Now my issue is whenever I try to validate my SOAP request against this XSD schema , I get the following error :-

```
Not valid.
Error - Line 1, 133: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 133; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'soapenv:Envelope'.
```

Please help ... I need to know what should I modify in my XSD schema so that the SOAP request/response gets validate against the XSD schema ... Since I am new in this and tried searching all over the internet, I didn't get suitable answer ... Please help

Comment: This solution is basically SOAP XML validation against XSD. not xml against XSD.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SOAP request and response don't validate against *your* schema, but the *SOAP schema*. You can use your XSD to validate your request and response *if you import* the SOAP XSD into it:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1" 
    xmlns:tns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
            schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></import>

...
```

You don't have to do that if your *instance* declares a `schemaLocation` attribute mapping the namespaces of both schemas (yours and the SOAP schema) to their locations:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1 your-schema.xsd
                        http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <retrieveDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
            <Response>The Data retrieved from the Database</Response>
            <Id>58</Id>
            <Name>fdfdf</Name>
            <Age>44</Age>
            <Designation>sse</Designation>
        </retrieveDataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: The second option achieves the same result. It simply transfers to the instances the responsibility for finding the soap schemas. In the case where you couldn't change your schemas (to add the *import*) you could link both of them to your instances using the second option and still validate the files.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and for me schema import didn't work.
Stack:

```
    10:18:03,206 | DEBUG | iEsb | DefaultValidationErrorHandler    |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Validation error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'soapenv:Envelope'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'soapenv:Envelope'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:233)[:]
```

My java version was: 1.6.0_45.
But I solved it through downloading xsd and importing it as a file:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="envelope.xsd" />
```

Maybe it will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

So, the final solution that worked for me is using import :-

```
<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
            schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></import>
```